# Mystery spacing on svg web graphic

Tags: html, css, svg

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/17/

This is my code for the SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"> /* this here */
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

I've tried a few different things, but it seems that although in theory the circle should hit the very top and bottom of the blue box, it instead leaves a space. I've tried this:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

All to no avail. Can anyone please tell me why the circle doesn't fill up this area completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic geometry.

Your numbers must be such that `(r * 2) + strokeWidth = height`

In this case, if you want to keep `stroke-width="4"`, then you want
`r = (height - strokeWidth) / 2 = 96 / 2 = 48`

So:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
```